# Refer a jar which is inside a zip folder in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am working on maven multi module project and the maven version is 3.0.3.
The parent pom needs a particular jar which is inside a zip folder in Nexus. 
So, I have included the dependency as below in the parent pom file.

```
<properties>
<standalonejar_version>5.5.0</standalonejar_version>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>standalonejar</artifactId>
  <version>${standalonejar_version}</version>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Looks like it is not working and also, there are other modules in the same project which require that particular jar.

So, can you please help how to refer that particular jar which is inside the zip folder. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Uh... first of all, why is there a .jar placed in a .zip?

Comment: because the previous project's final artifact (which is the above particular jar I am talking about) need to be packed as a zip along with its dependencies to deploy to the server. So thats why I zipped all of them.